# how to stop seeping ground lake water coming into our cottage basement at times of extrem runoff pressure from river

Tags: water-pressure

We have a lovely walk out house at Wasa Lake, B.C. We are retiring there this year and would like to use the walk out for addition living space. Had the house since 2005 and had no issues with flooding. However the last three years we have had flooding. The ground under the house is very porous and the pressure from high run off pushes the water up through the ground and then seeps into the lower level. Is there someway we can stop the water coming in with out worrying about flooding or the pressure cracking the basement cement floor? We do have a sump pump. Neighbors took out all the water and cracked their basement floor due to pressure buildup. We left 2 feet of water in to prevent this and were successful. Looking at every avenue to solve this problem. Thanks for any input. Penny

Comment: You left 2 feet of water in what? How is the sump not achieving your goal? Please update your question to clarify.

Comment: I think he's saying that when the neighbors pumped out all of the water from their basement, the water made the basement act like a boat and the buoyant force of the water cracked the floor. By leaving a couple feet of water in the basement, she prevented this from happening, but obviously it's not ideal.

Comment: Run off doesn't cause up-ward pressure. Upward water pressure is coming from the water table. Sounds like your water table is higher than the bottom of your basement. Not a whole lot you can do about that.

Comment: Yeah. There is no fix for the water table being higher than your basement. As long as it is only seasonal you can compensate by making sure everything in the basement is impervious to water and make sure the sump and drainage system are working properly.

Comment: Well, there -might- be a way to alter the lay of the land or its drainage around the house to push the water table down a few feet.  They drained the whole Great Black Swamp with steam ditchers and drain tile.